# Defining a function to find the unique palindromes in a given string

Tags: python-3.x, function, palindrome

I'm kinda new to python.I'm trying to define a function when asked would give an output of only unique words which are palindromes in a string.

I used `casefold()` to make it case-insensitive and `set()` to print only uniques.

Here's my code:

```
def uniquePalindromes(string):
    x=string.split()
    for i in x:
        k=[]
        rev= ''.join(reversed(i))
        if i.casefold() == rev.casefold():
            k.append(i.casefold())
            print(set(k))
        else:
            return
```

I've tried to run this line

```
print( uniquePalindromes('Hanah asked Sarah but Sarah refused') )
```

The expected output should be `['hanah','sarah']` but its returning only `{'hanah'}` as the output. Please help.

Comment: `sarah` is not a palindrome. `'sarah' != 'haras'`.

Comment: You'e not not returning anything.  A bare 'return`  returns `None`.  `return k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is sound, and your function is mostly doing what you want it to. Part of the issue is how you're *returning* things - all you're doing is printing the set of each individual word. For example, when I take your existing code and do this:

```
>>> print(uniquePalindromes('Hannah Hannah Alomomola Girafarig Yes Nah, Chansey Goldeen Need log'))
{'hannah'}
{'alomomola'}
{'girafarig'}
None
```

`hannah`, `alomomola`, and `girafarig` are the palindromes I would expect to see, but they're not given in the format I expect. For one, they're being *printed*, instead of *returned*, and for two, that's happening one-by-one.

And the function is returning `None`, and you're trying to print that. This is not what we want.

---

Here's a fixed version of your function:

```
def uniquePalindromes(string):
    x=string.split()
    k = []  # note how we put it *outside* the loop, so it persists across each iteration without being reset
    for i in x:
        rev= ''.join(reversed(i))
        if i.casefold() == rev.casefold():
            k.append(i.casefold())  
            # the print statement isn't what we want
        # no need for an else statement - the loop will continue anyway
    # now, once all elements have been visited, return the set of unique elements from k
    return set(k)
```

now it returns roughly what you'd expect - a *single* set with multiple words, instead of printing multiple sets with one word each. Then, we can print that set.

```
>>> print(uniquePalindromes("Hannah asked Sarah but Sarah refused"))
{'hannah'}
>>> print(uniquePalindromes("Hannah and her friend Anna caught a Girafarig and named it hannaH"))
{'anna', 'hannah', 'girafarig', 'a'}
```

Comment: If there are no palindromes in the string which I'm working on, is there a way to return an empty set. I thought using `return none` would help do that but it didnt work as planned.

Comment: @JBlack My updated version will actually do that! Try `print(uniquePalindromes("there are no palindromes in this sentence"))`, which will print `set()` - an empty set. This happens because, if there were no palindromes, then nothing was added to the list `k`, so the set we create from it is empty.

Comment: I'm trying to print a set in reverse lexicographic order, so I've changed the code to this: `def uniquePalindromes(string):
    x=string.split()
    k=[]
    for i in x:
        rev= ''.join(reversed(i))
        if i.casefold() == rev.casefold():
            k.append(i.casefold())
            k=sorted(k,reverse=True)
    return list(set(k)) ` . But this is returning 'anna','hannah' instead of 'hannah','anna'. Is this the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @JBlack Putting it into a `set` will probably mess up the ordering. I would do the conversion from set to list first, e.g. `return sorted(list(set(k)), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

they are not gonna like me on here if I give you some tips. But try to divide the amount of characters (that aren't whitespace) into 2. If the amount on each side is not equivalent then you must be dealing with an  odd amount of letters. That means that you should be able to traverse the palindrome going downwards from the middle and upwards from the middle, comparing those letters together and using the middle point as a "jump off" point. Hope this helps